# Twitter User Agent on Sharing

Tags: twitter

When someone tweets sometime to a page, and twitter crawls the page for data such as checking Twitter Cards, does anyone know what User Agent Twitter uses?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Twitter uses the User-Agent of **Twitterbot** (with version, such as `Twitterbot/1.0`) when crawling pages to find Twitter Cards markup. Twitter's crawler respects `robots.txt` when scanning URLs if you ever need to create exceptions.

Read more on [Twitter Cards URL Crawling & Caching](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started#crawling).